# Difference in CP Report and Console Report Data

Tags: php, rightnow-crm

I have a report (Let's say report ID is 101010) generated via the Console and it's printing out the following results:

```
+----------+-----+
| Category | NoI |
+----------+-----+
| C        | 102 |
| A        |  98 |
| E        |  90 |
| D        |  74 |
| B        |  60 |
+----------+-----+
```

When I try to use the same report ID on the CP page via the widget's controller, I get the following result:

```
+----------+-----+
| Category | NoI |
+----------+-----+
| D        |  32 |
| A        |  25 |
| B        |   6 |
+----------+-----+
```

Here is the code of my widget's controller:

```
function getData() {
    $filters = array();
    $format = array();
    $report_id = $this->data['attrs']['report_id'];
    echo $report_id; // this is printing 101010
    $reportToken = \RightNow\Utils\Framework::createToken($report_id);
    $report_data = $this->CI->model('Report')->getDataHTML(
       $report_id, $reportToken, $filters, $format
    );   
    print_r($report_data);
}
```

So what I'm not able to figure out is:

- Why is there a difference in the data?
- Why only 3 categories (instead of 5) are pulled via the CP widget controller?

  - One thing I noticed was that there was a property inside `$report_data` called as `per_page` and its value was **3**. Is this the reason for pulling only the first 3 records? If yes, how would I increase that value?

## UPDATE

After some R&D, I think I found out that the reason there is a change in data is because on the CP, the data is pulled for the incidents raised only by the logged in user whereas the data from the Console includes incidents raised by everyone.

So how would I remove the built-in filter that is being added to the report?

Answer (score 1):

You were more likely at the result when reviewing the per page attribute.  Both the Report model and variable widgets implement that attribute.  Analytics reports themselves implement pagination.  So, either the report has a default page variable set to three, or you are setting it somewhere else (inadvertently perhaps). See if changing the `per_page` filter works:

```
function getData() {
    $filters = array('per_page' => 50);
    $format = array();
    $report_id = $this->data['attrs']['report_id'];
    echo $report_id; // this is printing 101010
    $reportToken = \RightNow\Utils\Framework::createToken($report_id);
    $report_data = $this->CI->model('Report')->getDataHTML(
       $report_id, $reportToken, $filters, $format
    );   
    print_r($report_data);
}
```

Comment: The `per_page` isn't taking effect because I found out that the account with which I logged in had 3 incidents raised against it and hence only 3 were showing up. So my assumption of the data being filtered based on logged in user is correct.
My question is how would I remove that filter (supposedly auto-added by the system and not me). `getRunTimeFilters()` is returning empty also. I think the function which is adding that filter is `addContactInformation()` in the Report model

Comment: What data does the report return?  Could the permissions on those objects be the issue for your account?  For instances, if this is a product, then maybe it isn't set to show on CP, which would explain the applied filter outside of your code.

Comment: The report returns 5 rows when run from console and only 3 when run on the CP (via the `<rn:widget path="Standard/report/Grid2">` code). I don't think there are any permission issues as the account with which I logged into CP is a full admin access account.
Anyways, I simply ROQL'd the data myself instead of using the report Model and solved the issue. Thanks for your time. +1 btw

Answer (score 0):

There is a line in the report model which is probably adding the filter. Try removing this line and see what happens.

```
 $searchArgs['search_field' . $index++] = $this->toFilterArray("$contactSessionAlias.c_id", OPER_EQ, " $contactID");
```